# Cocos2d/Box2d game not running well on iPad Air

Tags: ios, performance, cocos2d-iphone, ios7, box2d

I was about 95% done with my first cocos2d 2 / Box2d game when the iPad air was released. The game was running perfectly smoothly on an iPad mini, but on the Air it does not run smoothly at all - lots of stuttering and jerky movement, but with a frame rate of 60!

I use a fixed time step, and after lengthy investigation, I found that by increasing the value of MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME from 2 to 3 the Air would run smoothly, but the mini then runs badly.

So my question is, has anyone run into this and how might this be solved? I guess I could try to determine the H/W and change the value, but there must be a good reason for the disruption and a better way to accommodate all devices.

Thanks
TinoK

Adding code snippet...

```
- (void) update:(ccTime) dt {

static double UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1.0f/60.0f;
static double MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME = 2; // 3 or more makes iPad air happy and iPad mini unhappy
static double timeAccumulator = 0;

timeAccumulator += dt;
if (timeAccumulator > (MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME * UPDATE_INTERVAL)) {

    timeAccumulator = UPDATE_INTERVAL;
}

// Advance score multiplier timeout
if (_scoreMultiplierTimeout > 0.0) {

    _scoreMultiplierTimeout -= dt;

    if (_scoreMultiplierTimeout <= 0.0) {

        _scoreMultiplierTimeout = 0.0;
        _scoreMultiplier = 1;
    }
}

//int32 velocityIterations = 8;
//int32 positionIterations = 1;

int32 velocityIterations = 3;
int32 positionIterations = 2;

while (timeAccumulator >= UPDATE_INTERVAL) {

    timeAccumulator -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
    _world->Step(UPDATE_INTERVAL, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
    _world->ClearForces();

    // Iterate over the bodies in the physics world
    for (b2Body* b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) {

        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {

...
```

Comment: post the code that shows how you update the physics world

Comment: Code added. Incidentally, changes to velocityIterations and positionIterations was part of my trial & error investigation - It made no difference. Also note, iPhone 5 is also happy with MAX_CYCLES_PER_FRAME = 2 and unhappy with a value of 3.

Comment: stepping multiple times per frame and at the same time incorporating delta time into updates makes no sense. Use a fixed time step, and step only once per frame. Increase iteration counts if you encounter simulation accuracy issues.

Comment: I think I understand... I have removed all of the time accumulator stuff and am relying on the update to get called 60 times a second - In it I update the step once and the sprite positions once. It all works very well, but then what would happen if the update call takes more than 1/60 secs to execute? And what was the use of all of the accumulator stuff anyway?

Comment: If the framerate drops below 60 fps with a fixed physics timestep, then the physics simulation slows down. This is actually good because applying delta time to physics leads to possible problematic behavior. More details here: http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.learn-cocos2d.com%2F2013%2F10%2Fgame-engine-multiply-delta-time-or-not%2F&ei=NE-WUryMEOaBywPg1oKoCQ&usg=AFQjCNGfXqe0vYtqxtgNHljV4Nb645eNMQ&sig2=cg0Z4YHnYGao68RI6YTTUA&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bGQ

Comment: Its looks like the link (and the entire site) you referenced is down, so I will read that later. For the time-being, your suggestion helped solve my problem - Thank you for that.

Comment: site is back up again